# Passing variable in Django form that user can't edit

Tags: django, django-forms, django-sessions

I'd like to generate a random 1-time passcode for a user that appears as a disabled field in a Django form.

The passcode will be shown in the form to the user on the page, and the user will not be able to edit it, but it will be submitted with the form. I do not want my users to set their own passcodes, but I want to tell them what their passcode is.

What is the best way to ensure that the 1-time passcode that is generated for users is not edited by users? I have been using session variables to remember the value so that I can confirm it has not been tampered with upon submit.

```
def my_page(request):

    # If submitted
    if request.method == "POST":

        # Check to make sure passcode wasn't altered
        if (request.POST.get('passcode') == request.session['pw']):
             ... rest of function here ...

    # Generate passcode and store it the session
    request.session['pw'] = genRandomPassword()

    # Init the form with a passcode
    form = MyForm(initial={'passcode': request.session['pw']})
    return render(request, 'example.html', {'form': form})
```

Is there a better method for accomplishing what I am attempting to do? I think what I am doing works, as long as users can't edit their session variables. It does break if a user opens up another tab, as then a second passcode session variable will be generated.

I do not want to store the passcodes in a database.

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of checking `request.POST.get('passcode') == request.session['pw']` simply ignore the data inside `POST` and use data from `session` so even a user somehow changes the password you won't care about it (note that you don't even need to add `pw` to the form, it can be a template context variable)

Note: I personally think your solution is not a good idea, do not generate a password before submit, let the user fill the form and after successful submit generate their random password, after submitting show a page to user saying your form was submitted and your password is `blah blah`

Note 2: problem with your solution is assume I open a page and my generated password is `1` then I open a new tab and my generated password is `2`, (and now `2` is stored in session as `pw`) I go and fill the form on the first page and submit it. what happens now? with your sample code you have to show an error to user, but user didn't to anything wrong, and with my fix (first paragraph) user thinks her password is `1` but it's actually `2`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I like to give the passcode before the need it. And yes -- that is true about opening new tabs generating new passwords. Right now I just return an error message.

Comment: I have addressed 2 as I do not create a new password in the session variable until the old password is considered used.